# Правильный вывод из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть комментарии и под.комменты, все это в одной базе, каждый под.коммент содержит в своей строке id в поле базы parent_com_id, если комментарий главный пишется 0. задача вывести 10 главных комментариев содержащих в себе под.комменты.

```
$w = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_com_id!='0';"));

$li = $_GET['lim'];
$lim = 10+$li+$w;

$q = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $lim;");
```

Первой строкой получал количество под.комментов страницы и далее прибавлял к числу нужных для вывода т.е. для 10 штук. вторая строке - гет - это подгрузка комментариев.

Сначала, как я думал, все было отлично, но проверив на большей нагрузке, при большем количестве комментариев и оказалось совсем не норм.

Comment: самое простое - добавьте memcache, что бы кешировать запросы.

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е. чтобы все комментарии страницы кэшировались? и из кэша уже выводились? а как же страница модеров, где выводятся все комментарии сайта, а их может быть очень много т.к. сайт популярен)

Comment: @singmen так и там кешируйте, в чем проблема то

Comment: @Rnddev, проблема в установке на сервер memcache и правильном составлении кода

Answer (score 1):

1. Количество ваших под комментариев можно получить иным способом:
   `SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE parent_com_id != '0'`
2. Можно использовать [пагинацию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), чтобы не обрабатывать|выводить слишком большое 
   количество данных